# Use concurrent.futures with new tasks for a real-time scenario

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, concurrency, queue

It is fairly easy to do parallel work with Python 3's `concurrent.futures` module as shown below.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    future_to = {executor.submit(do_work, input, 60): input for input in dictionary}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to):
        data = future.result()
```

It is also very handy to insert and retrieve items into a Queue.

```
q = queue.Queue()
for task in tasks:
q.put(task)
while not q.empty():
   q.get()
```

I have a script running in background listening for updates. Now, in theory assume that, as those updates arrive, I would queue them and do work on them concurrently using the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Now, individually, all of these components work in isolation, and make sense, but how do I go about using them together? I am not aware if it is possible to feed the `ThreadPoolExecutor` work from the queue in real time unless the data to work from is predetermined?

In a nutshell, all I want to do is, receive updates of say 4 messages a second, shove them in a queue, and get my concurrent.futures to work on them. If I don't, then I am stuck with a sequential approach which is slow.

Let's take the [canonical example in the Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) documentation below:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

The list of `URLS` is fixed. Is it possible to feed this list in real-time and get the worker to process it as they come by, perhaps from a queue for management purposes? I am a bit confused on whether my approach is *actually possible*?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) from the Python docs, expanded to take its work from a queue.  A change to note, is that this code uses `concurrent.futures.wait` instead of `concurrent.futures.as_completed` to allow new work to be started while waiting for other work to complete.

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
import time
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

def feed_the_workers(spacing):
    """ Simulate outside actors sending in work to do, request each url twice """
    for url in URLS + URLS:
        time.sleep(spacing)
        q.put(url)
    return "DONE FEEDING"

def load_url(url, timeout):
    """ Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents """
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:

    # start a future for a thread which sends work in through the queue
    future_to_url = {
        executor.submit(feed_the_workers, 0.25): 'FEEDER DONE'}

    while future_to_url:
        # check for status of the futures which are currently working
        done, not_done = concurrent.futures.wait(
            future_to_url, timeout=0.25,
            return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED)

        # if there is incoming work, start a new future
        while not q.empty():

            # fetch a url from the queue
            url = q.get()

            # Start the load operation and mark the future with its URL
            future_to_url[executor.submit(load_url, url, 60)] = url

        # process any completed futures
        for future in done:
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
            else:
                if url == 'FEEDER DONE':
                    print(data)
                else:
                    print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))

            # remove the now completed future
            del future_to_url[future]
```

Output from fetching each `url` twice:

```
'http://www.foxnews.com/' page is 67574 bytes
'http://www.cnn.com/' page is 136975 bytes
'http://www.bbc.co.uk/' page is 193780 bytes
'http://some-made-up-domain.com/' page is 896 bytes
'http://www.foxnews.com/' page is 67574 bytes
'http://www.cnn.com/' page is 136975 bytes
DONE FEEDING
'http://www.bbc.co.uk/' page is 193605 bytes
'http://some-made-up-domain.com/' page is 896 bytes
'http://europe.wsj.com/' page is 874649 bytes
'http://europe.wsj.com/' page is 874649 bytes
```

Comment: Many thanks, can you tell me why is the output like that, as I have edited in your answer above. The URLs were only 5, but it seems like it is running some more than once.

Comment: If you look at the feeder function, I went through the URL list twice because it made the testing more interesting.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Many thanks. I get it for the most part, but don't understand why you added `del future_to_url[future]` in the last line.

Comment: That dict is constantly being passed to wait(), so it is good to prune the completed futures.

Comment: A little confused on the real-time scenario. I have a handler that receives messages in real-time. I am doing `q.put(task)` inside the handler, so I don't really have provision to do something as `executor.submit(feed_the_workers, 0.25): 'FEEDER DONE'}` as my feed_the_workers is essentially a streaming handler adding messages to the queue. How would this work then? Also, the streaming handler is a forever script.

Comment: That part of the code is strictly for the simulation. So you would not launch `feed_the_workers`. But I assume that the `q.put(task)` is being done on a different thread than the thread (main in this example) that is managing the `futures`.  My assumption is that the while loop that is terminated when the `future_to_url` is empty would be terminated with completely different logic that is dependent on your application.  Which in your case sounds like it would be `while True:`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133170/discussion-between-ali-gajani-and-stephen-rauch).

Comment: I wonder how trivial it would be to expand the usage of this to multiple processes, simply changing `ThreadPoolExecutor` to `ProcessPoolExecutor` will not work due to the shared `queue.Queue` instance...

Comment: In fact, using a multiprocessing Manager object with a multiprocessing queue works, since concurrent.futures is compatible with the multiprocessing library:

`m = multiprocessing.Manager()`
`q = m.Queue()`

Answer (score 7):

At work I found a situation where I wanted to do parallel work on an unbounded stream of data. I created a small library inspired by the excellent answer already provided by Stephen Rauch.

I originally approached this problem by thinking about two separate threads, one that submits work to a queue and one that monitors the queue for any completed tasks and makes more room for new work to come in. This is similar to what Stephen Rauch proposed, where he consumes the stream using a `feed_the_workers` function that runs in a separate thread.

Talking to one of my colleagues, he helped me realize that you can get away with doing everything in a single thread if you define a buffered iterator that allows you to control how many elements are let out of the input stream every time you are ready to submit more work to the thread pool.

So we introduce the `BufferedIter` class

```
class BufferedIter(object):
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iter = iterator

    def nextN(self, n):
        vals = []
        for _ in range(n):
            vals.append(next(self.iter))
        return vals
```

which allows us to define the stream processor in the following way

```
import logging
import queue
import signal
import sys
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait, ALL_COMPLETED

level = logging.DEBUG
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s'))
handler.setLevel(level)
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(level)

WAIT_SLEEP = 1  # second, adjust this based on the timescale of your tasks


def stream_processor(input_stream, task, num_workers):

    # Use a queue to signal shutdown.
    shutting_down = queue.Queue()

    def shutdown(signum, frame):
        log.warning('Caught signal %d, shutting down gracefully ...' % signum)
        # Put an item in the shutting down queue to signal shutdown.
        shutting_down.put(None)

    # Register the signal handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown)

    def is_shutting_down():
        return not shutting_down.empty()

    futures = dict()
    buffer = BufferedIter(input_stream)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(num_workers) as executor:
        num_success = 0
        num_failure = 0
        while True:
            idle_workers = num_workers - len(futures)

            if not is_shutting_down():
                items = buffer.nextN(idle_workers)
                for data in items:
                    futures[executor.submit(task, data)] = data

            done, _ = wait(futures, timeout=WAIT_SLEEP, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
            for f in done:
                data = futures[f]
                try:
                    f.result(timeout=0)
                except Exception as exc:
                    log.error('future encountered an exception: %r, %s' % (data, exc))
                    num_failure += 1
                else:
                    log.info('future finished successfully: %r' % data)
                    num_success += 1

                del futures[f]

            if is_shutting_down() and len(futures) == 0:
                break

        log.info("num_success=%d, num_failure=%d" % (num_success, num_failure))
```

Below we show an example for how to use the stream processor

```
import itertools

def integers():
    """Simulate an infinite stream of work."""
    for i in itertools.count():
        yield i


def task(x):
    """The task we would like to perform in parallel.
    With some delay to simulate a time consuming job.
    With a baked in exception to simulate errors.
    """
    time.sleep(3)
    if x == 4:
        raise ValueError('bad luck')
    return x * x

stream_processor(integers(), task, num_workers=3)
```

The output for this example is shown below

```
2019-01-15 22:34:40,193 future finished successfully: 1
2019-01-15 22:34:40,193 future finished successfully: 0
2019-01-15 22:34:40,193 future finished successfully: 2
2019-01-15 22:34:43,201 future finished successfully: 5
2019-01-15 22:34:43,201 future encountered an exception: 4, bad luck
2019-01-15 22:34:43,202 future finished successfully: 3
2019-01-15 22:34:46,208 future finished successfully: 6
2019-01-15 22:34:46,209 future finished successfully: 7
2019-01-15 22:34:46,209 future finished successfully: 8
2019-01-15 22:34:49,215 future finished successfully: 11
2019-01-15 22:34:49,215 future finished successfully: 10
2019-01-15 22:34:49,215 future finished successfully: 9
^C <=== THIS IS WHEN I HIT Ctrl-C
2019-01-15 22:34:50,648 Caught signal 2, shutting down gracefully ...
2019-01-15 22:34:52,221 future finished successfully: 13
2019-01-15 22:34:52,222 future finished successfully: 14
2019-01-15 22:34:52,222 future finished successfully: 12
2019-01-15 22:34:52,222 num_success=14, num_failure=1
```

Comment: Looks like a hard solution

Comment: Thanks for this answer. can you explain what the frame variable in the shutdown function does?

Comment: +1. Very interesting approach and useful library. Have made use of it. However, I suggest a little modification as follows.

Answer (score 1):

I really liked the interesting approach by @pedro above. However, when processing thousands of files, I noticed that at the end a StopIteration would be thrown and some files would always be skipped. I had to make a little modification to as follows. Very useful answer again.

```
class BufferedIter(object):
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iter = iterator

    def nextN(self, n):
        vals = []
        try:
            for _ in range(n):
                vals.append(next(self.iter))
            return vals, False
        except StopIteration as e:
            return vals, True
```

-- Call as follows

```
...
if not is_shutting_down():
   items, is_finished = buffer.nextN(idle_workers)
   if is_finished:
        stop()
...
```

-- Where stop is a function that simply tells to shutdown

```
def stop():
    shutting_down.put(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to gain the benefits of the executor without strictly having to use a Queue. New tasks are submitted from the main thread. The undone futures are tracked and waited on until all futures are done.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import sys
import time

sys.setrecursionlimit(64)  # This is only for demonstration purposes to trigger a RecursionError. Do not set in practice.


def slow_factorial(n: int) -> int:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * slow_factorial(n-1)


initial_inputs = [0, 1, 5, 20, 200, 100, 50, 51, 55, 40, 44, 21, 222, 333, 202, 1000, 10, 9000, 9009, 99, 9999]

for executor_class in (concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor, concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor):
    for max_workers in (4, 8, 16, 32):
        start_time = time.monotonic()
        with executor_class(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
            futures_to_n = {executor.submit(slow_factorial, n): n for n in initial_inputs}
            while futures_to_n:
                futures_done, futures_not_done = concurrent.futures.wait(futures_to_n, return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED)
                # Note: Length of futures_done is often > 1.
                for future in futures_done:
                    n = futures_to_n.pop(future)
                    try:
                        factorial_n = future.result()
                    except RecursionError:
                        n_smaller = int(n ** 0.9)
                        future = executor.submit(slow_factorial, n_smaller)
                        futures_to_n[future] = n_smaller
                        # print(f'Failed to compute factorial of {n}. Trying to compute factorial of a smaller number {n_smaller} instead.')
                    else:
                        # print(f'Factorial of {n} is {factorial_n}.')
                        pass
        used_time = time.monotonic() - start_time
        executor_type = executor_class.__name__.removesuffix('PoolExecutor').lower()
        print(f'Workflow took {used_time:.1f}s with {max_workers} {executor_type} workers.')
    print()
```

Output:

```
Workflow took 9.4s with 4 thread workers.
Workflow took 6.3s with 8 thread workers.
Workflow took 5.4s with 16 thread workers.
Workflow took 5.2s with 32 thread workers.

Workflow took 9.0s with 4 process workers.
Workflow took 5.9s with 8 process workers.
Workflow took 5.1s with 16 process workers.
Workflow took 4.9s with 32 process workers.
```

For more clarity, uncomment the two commented `print` statements. As per the output above, there is an asymptotic speed benefit with more workers.