# Is it possible to add new jobs dynamically using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

The use case I have in mind is as follows: I would like to start a range of jobs with **ThreadPoolExecutor** and then when a job completes, I would like to add a new job to the queue. I would also like to know when the next job finishes and repeat the procedure above. After I have had the opportunity to observe a predefined number of results, I would like to terminate everything properly. For instance, consider the following code, where the commented out bits in the **run_con** method show what I would like to achieve.

```
import numpy as np
import time
from concurrent import futures
MAX_WORKERS = 20
seed = 1234
np.random.seed(seed)
MSG = "Wall time: {:.2f}s"

def expensive_function(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return x

def run_con(func, ts):
    t0 = time.time()
    workers = min(MAX_WORKERS, len(ts))
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(workers) as executor:
        jobs = []
        for t in ts:
            jobs.append(executor.submit(func, t))
        done = futures.as_completed(jobs)
        for future in done:
            print("Job complete: ", future.result())
            # depending on some condition, add new job to jobs, e.g.
            # jobs.append(func, np.random.random())
            # update done generator
            # if a threshold on total jobs is reached, close every thing down sensibly.
    print(MSG.format(time.time()-t0))

ts = np.random.random(10)*5
print("Sleep times: ", ts)
run_con(expensive_function, ts)
```

Is this achievable with concurrent.futures? If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648103/how-would-i-go-about-using-concurrent-futures-and-queues-for-a-real-time-scenari

Comment: I have added a new [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75569605/) which does not require a `Queue`.